# What cause the "from review" links to appear in comments?

Tags: support, comments, review, automatic-comments

I sometimes see comments ending in "From Review" (hyperlinked to a review page) on questions and answers, e.g.

> [image]

I spend a good bit of time in the review queues (on Unix & Linux), but comments I make do not come with these "From Review" links.
Note that I only have access to the "First post" and "Late answer" queues.  Do these links only appear for the higher-rep queues?

Answer (score 2):

These links (almost) all come from auto-comments left by choosing from the list shown upon recommending or voting for deletion in the Low Quality Posts queue, which you get access to at 2000 rep on graduated sites and 1000 rep on betas. This is the only queue that has its own auto-comment system (although four queues on most sites allow you to mark questions as duplicates, and thus can leave duplicate auto-comments as normal), so it's the only queue that needs a way to mark that the comments were not actually hand-written.

Occasionally you will see some clever person leaving a similar-looking link at the end of a comment that is not part of the LQP set. As far as I know, those are all manually copy-pasted; in any case, there's a discernible, if subtle, difference in link punctuation styling between those links and the official system ones.

Many reviewers use [Auto-Review Comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) or similar, which has no built-in way to distinguish its templates from handwritten comments, and no easy way to add [From Review] links either.

Comment: Essential part which is missing is that those comments are used only when the reviewer choose to delete or recommend deletion of the post.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Fair.

Comment: And can't do without [FHRC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXoPG.png). :)